# Android: vlaue is being changed in the JSON string when passing it to the intent service class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest

I want to pass JSON string
`{"latitude":53.86907815,"longitude":10.66554789,"formatted":"24.04.2015 13:27:49","route":4}`

to the server every 60 seconds so I want to implement that with the help of service and AlarmManager but I am always getting old time `23.04.2015 18:37:49` value in the JSON string in the `onHandleintent()` method.  Are the AlramReceiver and AlramService being registered in  manifest correctly?

set alarm:

```
 String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);
             Intent aiAutostart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
             aiAutostart.putExtra("json_data", jSONString);
             PendingIntent  piAutostart = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), TypAutoStart, aiAutostart, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
             AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, piAutostart);
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          Intent service1 = new Intent(context, PostData.class);
           service1 = new Intent(context, PostData.class);
           service1.putExtra("Extraname", intent.getStringExtra("Extraname"));
           context.startService(service1);

    }

}
```

PostData class:

```
public class PostData extends IntentService {

    public PostData() {
        super("someone");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {




        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("json_data")) {
            String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");

            System.out.println("Output from onStartCommand " + jSONString);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

}
```

Manifest  part:

```
  <service android:name=".PostData" /> 

  <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
```

Comment: Timer is a good approach.

Comment: you created intent, put some data, wrapped it into pending intent and scheduled this intent for repeating execution. of course you'll get the same data every time, because you are starting service with intent with data, which you got from broadcast inent

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta: does that mean I have to delete the BroadcastReceiver class and just work with timer?

Comment: @nikis: And how can I do it to get it to wotk?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that you create an intent with the "json_data" extra and call the alarm manager to start your broadcast receiver periodically with the **same** intent.

In your activity just start the receiver/service with the alarm manager and build the JSON model in the receiver/service. In that case the time and everything else will be up to date.

Please also note that you can bypass the receiver and start just the service with the alarm manager.

```
final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostData.class);
final PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Nikis said, you are calculating the values just once  and then send them every minute.

You gotta re-calculate the values each time your intent fires, so you need to calculate them in your BroadcastReceiver.

Remember that the receiver jsut has 5 seconds to work, so if it needs longer, make the receiver start a `Service` and let that do the calculating.

Answer (score 0):

i think you try this code for getting system current time.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

to send every time to json.